# Model in form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading the guide on the ruby on rails. I stuck at here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller

I have doubt how they have used `form_with(model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ], local: true)`

In this what does the model attribute means and also what is the significance of `build` in `@article.comments.build`.

Can someone please explain me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`form_with model: ...`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) and [`form_for ...`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) both accept a [resource-oriented style](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style).

Your given example:

> ```
> [@article, @article.comments.build]
> ```

Will be translated to (assuming article with id 1):

```
POST /articles/1/comments
```

Passing an array as recourse will assume a nested or namespaced resource. The last item in the array should be resource to work on. If this last item is a new record the form will use `POST` if it is an existing resource `PUT` will be used.

Here are a few examples to clarify things:

```
[@existing_article]
# PUT /articles/1

[@new_article]
# POST /articles

[@article, @existing_comment]
# PUT /articles/1/comments/1

[@article, @new_comment]
# POST /articles/1/comments

[:admin, @existing_article]
# PUT /admin/articles/1

[:admin, @new_article]
# POST /admin/articles

[@article, :admin, @existing_comment]
# PUT /articles/1/admin/comments/1

[@article, :admin, @new_comment]
# POST /articles/1/admin/comments
```

In your scenario `@article.comments.build` sets the subject of the form builder to a comment (because it is the last item in the array) and dictates the path/URL and method used when submitting the form.

Comment: Why it is `:admin` not `@admin`

Comment: @sbak `:admin` in the example represents a [namespace](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing), not a [resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web). However if you have an admin resource you could use `@admin` as well. This is entirely depended upon the defined resources and namespaces in your routes.rb file.